# Get list of files using grep and AWK command in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I want to get list of files under current directory which contains any line starts with pattern `01`, followed by either of the number `01,02,03 or 04`, followed by `6510`. I have searched similar patterns in StackOverflow but I am unable to resolve the issue.

What I have done so far?

```
$grep '^01[01|02|03|04]6510' *.* | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

As per above code, it does not provide correct file names. Could you please provide me suggestion to modify the command? Thank you.

For example:

file1.txt

```
01046510Z 1D2017212456011C 0 120170926100175151CAD
```

file2.txt

```
01016510Z 1D2017212456
```

file3.txt

```
01006510Z 1D20
```

**Output:**

file1.txt
file2.txt

Comment: What you are looking for is `^01(01|02|03|04)6510`  -- https://regex101.com/r/i93vFm/1

Comment: @anubhava updated input and output examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `brackets` -- `[]` Which in regex mean a **range**

What you need is parentheses -- Which mean **either a OR b** separated by a pipe `|`

So `^01(01|02|03|04)6510` Translates into

Anything that starts with 01
**AND** contains *either* 01 02 03 04 **AFTER** 01
**AND** contains 6150 **AFTER** 01 (01 02 03 04)

[REFERENCE](https://regex101.com/r/i93vFm/1/)

Comment: or `010[1-4]6510`

Comment: Yup!  I though about that -- But I stayed with the OPs original "thought process" to avoid confusion.  But to be honest, I would probably opt for `010[1-4]` for it's simpler syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are close with the regexp, but note that you would not use `[]` because they are for matching a single character amongst various choices.  But you will need ordinary parentheses just to ensure that the `|` (or) operator acts on the relevant part of the expression.  You will need `egrep` because ordinary `grep` does not support all regular expressions.  And you probably want `*` instead of `*.*` unless all filenames contain a `.`.

This gives the following adapted version of your command line:

```
egrep '^01(01|02|03|04)6510' * | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

But there is an easier form using the `-l` option on `egrep` to just list matching files:

```
egrep -l '^01(01|02|03|04)6510' *
```

If you also want to search through any subdirectories, you could add the `-r` option (for *recursive*) on `egrep`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this whole thing with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk).  You also don't need logical OR as you can just factor out the `010` part and use the character class `[1-4]`

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /010[1-4]6510/{print FILENAME; nextfile}' file*.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

***Note***: `nextfile` will force awk to skip to the next file once it finds the first match which will speed up processing

You can also use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and stop at the first match with:

```
$ grep -m1 "^010[1-4]6510" -l file*.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```